# Rails - date input, allow only weekdays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form which has a field of type `Date`.
The following line creates an input for the field, where the user can choose the date.

```
<%= f.date_select :start_date %>
```

How can I make it display only weekdays as input options?

Comment: Try `<%= f.date_select :start_date, discard_month: true, discard_year: true %>` this.......

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do what you want with a date_select helper. You have two alternatives (and one isn't really an alternative):

1) Write a validation in the model that fails if the date selected is not a weekend; or

2) Use a JavaScript date picker (like [jQuery DatePicker](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails)), which is the only real solution. You can [disable specific days or categories of days](http://webtricksandtreats.com/disable-specific-days-jquery-ui-date-picker/) with DatePicker.